# How to share an Observable when it's running and resubscribe when it's not

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have an Observable and when I subscribe it I want:

- if it's is executing, return the result of the current execution
- if not, re/execute the Observable.

For example:

I have a `wait` function. This function wait 1 seconds and return the current `time()`

```
function wait(): Observable<number> {
  return new Observable<number>((observer) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next((new Date).getTime());
      observer.complete();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Now, I have a code that call this `wait` function every 0.4 seconds.

- The first call to `wait` (0.4 seconds) will wait 1 second and return the current time
- The second call to `wait` (0.8 seconds), because there is an execution of `wait`, will return the same observable of the first point and the same result
- The third call to `wait` (1.2 seconds) will wait again 1 second because there is not an execution
- Etc

Comment: Why the third call wait's 1s when the first call created a new Observable that will finish 1s after 0.4s = at 1.4s.

Comment: Probably you need exhaustMap()  https://github.com/btroncone/learn-rxjs/blob/master/operators/transformation/exhaustmap.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you example, I think the 3rd call should get the initial timestamp and the 4th call should get a new one.

Anyway you can do this by semi-sharing the Observable like this:

```js
const timeStream = timer(1000)
    .pipe(map(() => (new Date).getTime()), share(), take(1));

function wait(): Observable<number> {
    return timeStream;
}

setTimeout(() => wait().subscribe(console.log), 400);
setTimeout(() => wait().subscribe(console.log), 800);
setTimeout(() => wait().subscribe(console.log), 1200);
setTimeout(() => wait().subscribe(console.log), 1600);
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-wiqpbf

The key is share() and take(1) combo - essentially this will make the Observable shared only when it is 'running'.

---

OP's final solution:

```js
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {share, take} from 'rxjs/operators';

function myFunction(): Observable<number> {
  return new Observable<number>((observer) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next((new Date).getTime());
      observer.complete();
    }, 1000);
  });
}

const task$ = myFunction().pipe(share(), take(1));

setInterval(() => {
  task$.subscribe(console.log);
}, 400);
```

Comment: @JoniJnm your final solution is mixing Observables and standard JS scheduling primitives. Why? I would recommend sticking with Observables or vanilla JS - your approach has for example problem with unsubscription/cancellation where `setTimeout` is not canceled.